# How to create a function object jQuery alike

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

I want to know how did jQuery make statement to make '$' or 'jquery' variable work in both way? I am not sure I am using the right words to describe this, but the example when we use jQuery:

```
$.foo()  // $ as object
$(element).foo() //$ as function
```

For what I tried:

```
var Foo = function Foo (element) {}

Foo.prototype.A = function (){}

var $ = new Foo;

$.A() // this works

$(element).A() // unable to find defined function A, because $ != $()
```

or

```
function Foo (element) {}

Foo.A = function (){}

var $ = Foo;

$().A() // this works

$.A() // unable to find defined function A, because $() != $
```

Can you advise me what I am missing, how can I accomplish something like jQuery does?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Take a look at this: [Writing your own jQuery](http://dfsq.info/site/read/writing-your-own-jquery)

Comment: I don't see how `$().A()` could work in the second example, because `$()` returns `undefined`.

Comment: In JS functions are objects.

Comment: @JamesThorpe the code from your example URL, ion().each() will work, but icon.each() will not work, thank you for your reference but still cannot resolve my question how to make $.each() works. Can you give me more advise?

Answer (score 1):

if you want that your `$ = new Foo()` is a function, you have to return a function.

```
function Foo() {
  // ...
  var f = function(element) {console.log(element)}
  f.someProp = 'value';

  return f;
}

var y = new Foo()
y('bar')
// -> 'bar'
y.someProp
// -> 'value'
```

Comment: In tha case it would not act as an object though

Comment: In JS a function is an object ;)

Answer (score -2):

You can do it like below:

```
$.fn.foo = function(){
//Your code here
}

$(element).foo();
```